# validar numero en input y al mismo tiempo formatearlo en miles

Tags: javascript, jquery, formato

Buen día, tengo el siguiente código que formatea varios input que tienen la clase input_valores_provisionales, colocando punto cada tres caracteres de esta manera:

```
500.000.000
```

El código en si funciona perfecto por si solo ya que lo he comprobado.

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $(".input_valores_provisionales").on({
      "focus": function(event) {
        $(event.target).select();
      },
      "keyup": function(event) {
        $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
          return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{3})$/, '$1.$2')
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
        });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Por otra parte, debo validar que solo se escriban valores numéricos en los inputs mencionados, lo hago de esta manera:

```
$('.input_valores_provisionales').keyup(
    function()
    {
      var total = 0;
      //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
      $(".input_valores_provisionales").each(
        function()
        {
          //compruebo que lo digitado sea un numero
          if (!isNaN($(this).val()))
          {
            //convierto a entero la cadena del input en base 10
            var numero_entero = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
            total = total+numero_entero;
            //muestro la suma en el span
            if(isNaN(total))
            {
              $("#span_total_provisionales").text("Rellena todos los campos");
            }
            else {
              $("#span_total_provisionales").text("$"+total);
            }

          }
          else
          {
              alert("Debe ingresar un valor numerico");
              //borrar el contenido del input ya que no es numerico
              $(this).val('');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  );
```

Este código también funciona perfecto por si solo, me valida si escribo una letra alertando y borrando el input no importa la longitud siendo 5 o 5000000000

como ven ambos codigos por separado me funcionan de maravilla, el problema esta en que al poner a funcionar ambos códigos me funciona hasta cierta longitud del numero digitado, por ejemplo si quiero digitar 500.000.000

llega hasta 5.000.000 y justo al digitar el siguiente cero para pasar a 50.000.000 me sale el alert de que no es un numero, necesito que me permita escribir mínimo 9 caracteres es decir hasta 999.999.999

tambien he probado haciendolo con puntos para los primeros tres ceros de la izquierda a modo de centavos y luego con , como en la moneda de estados unidos de esta manera

5,000.000

alguna idea?

Comment: Despues de formatear un numero con separación de miles `isNaN()` retornara siempre false cuando tenga mas de un punto

Comment: en ese orden de ideas, se puede comprobar que en el input hayan valores de 0 al 9 y puntos? y no un valor numerico como tal para asi no usar isNaN

Comment: Claro, con una regexp como la que usas para reemplazar los caracteres para dar el formato

Answer (score -1):

te dejo un codigo espero te sea util:

```
<input id="number">
```

javascript:

```
$("#number").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
  }
});
```

[Pruebalo aqui !](https://jsfiddle.net/j0rxrun8/519/)

Comment: ¿Como resolvería la pregunta del OP este código de ejemplo?, sería conveniente agregar esa información. Revisar [answer].